# Why can't I access meta from a property defined in setupController?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In `setupController`, i have:

```
controller.set('products', 
  this.store.query('product', { 
    filter: { 'user-id': model.id }, 
    page: { number: (params.page ? params.page : 1) } 
  })
);
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "meta":{
        "page":{
            "number":1,
            "size":10,
            "total":17,
            "prev":null,
            "next":2,
            "first":1,
            "last":17
        }
    },
    "data":[{..}, {..}]
}
```

In the template, why does `{{log products.meta}}` return `undefined`?

I do the same query in a `model hook` and `meta` actually returns valid data. Is there something special going on with `setupController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing in your code is set the controllers `products` property to the **Promise** returned from `this.store.query`. You'll want to let that promise resolve before you set the property on the controller:

```js
this.store.query('product', { 
  filter: { 'user-id': model.id }, 
  page: { number: (params.page ? params.page : 1) } 
}).then(products => {
  controller.set('products', products);
});
```

That will make sure what you're actually assigning to the `products` property is the resolved models, not the promise.